# Rails - Docker - finding the Rails root path in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm working on a project that runs in docker containers, and our assets are not displaying locally. They're saving to the DB as they should, with the issue being the assets_path being created.

When I run the application locally (not in a container) and call Rails.root, I receive the full path (/home/projects/bla...)

When I call Rails.root in the docker container, I receive just '/bla'.

Is there any way of getting docker to figure out what the 'real' Rails root is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share your `Dokcerfile` that you use to build the docker image? Probably your app is being deployed inside the container in the `/bla` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project folder is mount to your docker container then you will have to explicitly declare `WORKDIR` by appending this line to your `Dockerfile` and rebuild the image.

`WORKDIR /home/projects/bla`

Hope it helps.